# Mac OS X problem accessing file via symlink

Tags: osx, files, symbolic-links

GNU Emacs 24 on El Capitan.  When opening a file whose path includes a directory which is a symlink, Emacs emits the following error:

```
*ERROR*: Wrong type argument: numberp, "Bus error: 10"
```

If I handle this error, then the file will open but Emacs will hang until it receives a SIGHUP.

The path is a volume mounted as a network share from a Linux VM running on the local machine.  It doesn't seem to occur on a local symlink, but I've only done a limited use case test of this.

I am not using org-mode, and have tried opening the file in Fundamental mode which results in the same problem of Emacs hanging.  I have started emacs without any .emacs file with the same result.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me.  `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Those seem like awfully special circumstances. Have you tried attaching `dtruss` to the emacs process? (Run `sudo dtruss -p PID`, where PID is the pid of the emacs process.) It might be of interest to see what system calls are made, and which of them fails. (Umm, I discovered just now how *old* this question is. Perhaps it's moot by now.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen it is old ... and I haven't figured out the solution.  I actually haven't had this situation since I posted the question so I haven't had a chance to submit a bug report.  I'll try this dtruss and see what insights it gets.